# how to calculated the complex number $(-1)^{3i}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

how to calculated $(-1)^{3i}$. Well I did the following:

$z=(-1)^{3i}$ implies $\log z = 3i\log -1 = 3i(0+i\pi) = -3\pi$

then

$z=e^{-3\pi}$, I am fine? I will appreciate any help

Thank you so much!!!

Comment: You might want to think about branches. You could also have chosen $\log(-1)$ to be $3i\pi$ or $5\pi i$.

Comment: Excuse me, do you mean choose arguments for the real number $-3\pi$? Thank you Kenta S.

Comment: No, you use $\log -1 = i\pi$, but as mentioned in my answer the $\log$ can have infinitely many values as $e^{2\pi i} = 1$, so you could have also chosen $\log -1 = 3i\pi$

Comment: Oh maybe , i got it, do you mean $-3k\pi$ right?

Comment: Close, I mean $i\pi + 2k \cdot i\pi$

Comment: Thank you anyone here, i got it!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pay attention about the logarithm! The logarithm has infinitely many branches in the complex number so you have to take the $\log$ with caution!

However, if you replace $-1$ with $e^{\pi i}$ you get
$$
z=(-1)^{3i} = e^{\pi i \cdot 3i} = e^{-3\pi}
$$

You see, that the result is the same as taking the logarithm, however your approach is mathematically spoken not fully correct as you need to make clear that you're using the main branch of the logarithm. You potentially could use any other branch of the logarithm which would add $2\pi i$ to the result and change everything up, so you would end up with a different result, in general:
$$
\log z =3i \log (-1) = 3i (i\pi + 2ki\pi)=-3\pi-6k\pi \Leftrightarrow z = e^{-3\pi(2k+1)}
$$
for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ arbitrary.

Answer (score 2):

Since $-1=e^{i\pi (2n+1)},$ we have $(-1)^{3i}=e^{-3\pi(2n+1)},$ where $n\in\mathbb{Z}.$

Comment: One has to be very careful with $(a^b)^c = a^{bc}$  and complex numbers, you might want to justify why the calculation is valid here.

Comment: Of course the equality doesn't make sense for complex numbers in general, but the answer is real above.